# RxJava noClassDefFoundError: rx.plugins.RxJavaPlugins on API 16

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application using RxJava and Retofit. When I test my code on API 23 I get no errors however when I test in API 15, my RxJava doesnt appear to work properly and my app crashes with error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at $Proxy1.createToken(Native Method)
at com.loginsignup.presenter.LoginPresenterImpl.tryToLogin(LoginPresenterImpl.java:39)
at com.loginsignup.view.LoginActivity.tryToLogin(LoginActivity.java:197)
at com.loginsignup.view.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:180)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.plugins.RxJavaPlugins
at rx.Observable.<clinit>(Observable.java:63)
at $Proxy1.createToken(Native Method) 
at com.gooroo.gooroo.loginsignup.presenter.LoginPresenterImpl.tryToLogin(LoginPresenterImpl.java:39) 
at com.gooroo.gooroo.loginsignup.view.LoginActivity.tryToLogin(LoginActivity.java:197) 
at com.gooroo.gooroo.loginsignup.view.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:180) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ex"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1 alpha"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.9.5.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.orhanobut:logger:1.12'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3@aar'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any idea why there is no issue on API 23, but when I run it on API 16 it crashes when I try to login which uses RxJava?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have tried navigating to the rx.plugins.RxJavaPlugins Class through stack trace, and i have that class defined there

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem here is may be you have not initialized MultiDex Option

**Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher**

> Android 5.0 and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively
>   supports loading multiple dex files from application APK files. ART
>   performs pre-compilation at application install time which scans for
>   classes(..N).dex files and compiles them into a single .oat file for
>   execution by the Android device. For more information on the Android
>   5.0 runtime, see Introducing ART.
>   This is the reason why your app is working fine on API level 21.

**Multidex support prior to Android 5.0**

> Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 use the Dalvik runtime
>   for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single
>   classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this
>   limitation, you can use the multidex support library, which becomes
>   part of the primary DEX file of your app and then manages access to
>   the additional DEX files and the code they contain.

So, Firstly making sure you have imported correct dependency, which It seems you did it.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

In your manifest add the `MultiDexApplication` class from the multidex support library to the application element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        // This will solved the problem
        android:name="YourAppName">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**This is how i solved my problem, even there is closed Git issue regarding the same.**

**EDIT**

```
public class YouAppName extends MultiDexApplication {
    ..  ..
}
```

I hope it will help you out.

Comment: I already have a package name though. I don't want to change the name, what should I do?

Comment: Instead of extending Application extend MultiDexApplication simple, you will be good to go, 
please accept my answer if i help you

Comment: Thank you for the support. Also it is easier to extend the full name: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication

Comment: I never thought that was multidex but that worked. so whats the difference between this way and the way in gradle ? 'multiDexEnabled true
' ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bikash, his top solution really works.Yet in my program,  my Application class has extended another ***Application. I finally solve this by overriding attachBaseContext(Context base) function in my application class to initial MultiDex. In a word, I do like this:

```
defaultConfig {//first step
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

dependencies {compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'}//second

 @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);//finally
}
```

You can get more information from [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html)