# Android: ClassNotFoundException while class is present

Tags: android

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: be.kdg.examen, PID: 4451
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{be.kdg.examen/be.kdg.examen.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "be.kdg.examen.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/be.kdg.examen-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/be.kdg.examen-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "be.kdg.examen.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/be.kdg.examen-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/be.kdg.examen-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I always get this error while trying to run the application. There is a MainActivity so I really don't know what the problem is.

[image: This is the file structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the multidex support. Please see the following thread

[FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.plugins.RxJavaHooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135068/fatal-exception-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-rx-plugins-rxjavahooks/43136880#43136880)

Answer (score 4):

You have to include **multiDex** in your application. This can be inferred from the following line of your logcat output:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "be.kdg.examen.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[
```

---

**What is multiDex and how does this solution solve the problem?**

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904835/7551190) to understand.

---

**The Solution**

*Step 1:* Add this to your dependencies.

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

*Step 2:* In your Gradle add `multiDexEnabled true`.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true    // add this line
    }
    ...
}
```

*Step 3:* In your manifest add **multiDex** application class.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 1):

it is looking for the class in the package `be.kdg.examen.MainActivity` whereas your MainActivity is in `be.kdg.examen.vraag5.MainActivity`

Please check what is the complete path mentioned in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file if its mentioned as `.MainActivity` change it to `.vraag5.MainActivity`